# LU factorization in C

Tags: c, matrix, numerical-methods

I'm having a problem with this code, it does LU factorization, but it works on 3x3 matrices, when I test a larger one like 4x4, the program breaks, and I don't know how to fix it and I don't understand where the error is If anyone can help me I would be extremely grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 4
#define pi 3.141592653589793
#define e 2.718281828459045

// Função para calcular os fatores L e U
void LU(double A[N][N], int n)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
            double m = A[i][k] / A[k][k];
            A[i][k] = m;
            for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
                A[i][j] = A[i][j] - m * A[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Função para resolver um sistema triangular inferior
void Lower(double L[N][N], double b[N], double y[N], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
        double s = 0; //soma
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            s = s + L[i][j] * y[j];
        }
        y[i] = b[i] - s;
    }
    return;
}

// Função para resolver um sistema triangular superior
void Upper(double U[N][N], double b[N], double x[N], int n) 
{
    x[n] = b[n] / U[n][n];
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        double s = 0; //soma
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
        {
            s = s + U[i][j] * x[j];
        }
        x[i] = (b[i] - s) / U[i][i];
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    double Ai[N][N] = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 7, 10}, {3, 8, 11, 15}, {4, 11, 15, 20} };
    double bi[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    double A[N][N];
    double y[N];
    double x[N];
    int n = N;
    
    printf("Matriz dada inicialmente:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%15f ", Ai[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    // Calcula os fatores L e U
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            A[i][j] = Ai[i][j];
        }
    }
    LU(A, n);

    // Resolvendo o sistema triangular inferior
   Lower(A, bi, y, n);

    // Resolvendo o sistema triangular superior
    Upper(A, y, x, n);
    

    // Imprime os resultados
    printf("\nMatriz Lower e Upper Juntas em uma Matriz[A]\n\nA =\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%15f ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nVetores Solucao:\ny =[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%15f ", y[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

    printf("x =[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%15f ", x[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

As it is, it returned to me:

```
Matriz dada inicialmente:
       1.000000        2.000000        3.000000        4.000000
       2.000000        5.000000        7.000000       10.000000
       3.000000        8.000000       11.000000       15.000000
       4.000000       11.000000       15.000000       20.000000

Matriz Lower e Upper Juntas em uma Matriz[A]

A =
       1.000000        2.000000        3.000000        4.000000
       2.000000        1.000000        1.000000        2.000000
       3.000000        2.000000        0.000000       -1.000000
       4.000000        3.000000       -1.#IND00       -1.#IND00
```

That should return:

```
Matriz dada inicialmente:
       1.000000        2.000000        3.000000        4.000000
       2.000000        5.000000        7.000000       10.000000
       3.000000        8.000000       11.000000       15.000000
       4.000000       11.000000       15.000000       20.000000

Matriz Lower e Upper Juntas em uma Matriz[A]

A =
       1.000000        2.000000        3.000000        4.000000
       2.000000        1.000000        1.000000        2.000000
       3.000000        2.000000        1.000000       -1.000000
       4.000000        3.000000        2.000000        1.000000
```

Comment: Looks like you are accessing out of bounds. https://godbolt.org/z/K89h65Gx3 `i < n+1` doesn't look right. `x[n] = b[n] / U[n][n];` is also a problem.

Comment: All three of your functions will cause `j` to be `n` and exceed the size of the 2D array. You can add: `assert((j >= 0) && (j < n))`. You can put this in a macro to generalize and add one for `i` as well

Comment: if you `#include <math.h>` don't provide constants for PI and E constants, as they are provided there as `M_PI` and `M_E` resp.